Be notified of new mail in any Maildir inbox under ~/Mail, in the Zsh shell
I have a cron job that fetches new mail from several mail servers every 20 minutes. The mail is automatically sorted into Maildir mailboxes in a hierarchy under ~/Mail.
I want to be notified in the shell if a new message has arrived in any local mailbox in the last 20 minutes.
I'm using the zsh shell.

Since Maildir mailboxes are used, new mail may be found by looking for any regular file in any directory called new under ~/Mail. We ignore the fact that for a directory to be a legal Maildir mailbox, it should contain the three subdirectories cur, new, and tmp; we naively assume that any directory called new is part of a valid Maildir mailbox.
If the following command returns any result, we will have at least one new message:
find ~/Mail -path '*/new/*' -type f -print

... or, if we want to avoid looking in cur directories (where already read mail is stored),
find ~/Mail -name cur -type d -prune -o -path '*/new/*' -type f -print

... or, we could look at the expansion of some zsh shell globbing pattern such as ~/Mail/**/new/*(.[1]) (expands to the pathname of the first regular file in any new directory beneath ~/Mail). If the expansion fails to match anything, there is no new mail.
We can make a shell function that uses the above to print a friendly notification if there is new mail:
check_mail () {
    if find ~/Mail -path '*/new/*' -type f -print | grep -q .
    then
        echo 'You have new mail' >&2
    fi
}

The grep -q . command generates a true condition for the if statement if there is any output from find.
Associating our function with the periodic "hook", the zsh shell can call the function periodically before printing the next primary prompt.  We use this to call the function automatically if more than $PERIOD number of seconds has passed since the last time it was called (the PERIOD variable is specific to the periodic hook used below).
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook periodic check_mail

PERIOD=1200    # 20 minutes

Now, whenever a new file is created in a new directory somewhere under ~/Mail, the text You have new mail will be displayed at some point within 20 minutes, assuming the shell is made to redraw the prompt.  If the mail is not read, the message will be displayed again in 20 minutes, before the shell redraws the prompt.
See also:

The zshmisc(1) manual about Hook Functions.
The zshcontrib(1) manual about Manipulating Hook Functions (the add-zsh-hook command).


in before anyone else jumping in regarding your find method and replace it with a glob: You could use -quit (on GNU find, don't know about other impls) to quit immediately after printing the first result, and instead of grepping for a result code, [[ ! -z "$(find…)" ]] maybe?

A compact yet elegant method without spawing find would probably be (tmp=( **/new/**(.Y1) ) ) 2&>/dev/null && return "you've got mail" . The glob flags here are . for "only regular files", Y# for "don't give me more than # results. intentionally not setting N for NULL_GLOB here: let the subshell error if it doesn't find something, then suppress that warning message, but deal with the exit code.

If the "cause an error intentionally" methodology doesn't sit well with you  (and that'd be understandable): tmp=(**/new/**(.NY1));[[ ${#tmp} -gt 0 ]] && echo "yo, Mail!";

@MarcusMüller Without being too theoretical about it, I perceived the file globbing alternative to be much slower than using find.  I have some fairly large cur directories (many thousands of messages), and it's difficult to avoid expanding these with the glob, but it's easy to avoid them with find.  As to quitting at the first find result, I think I thought I did that with grep -q . already (grep would only read the first line coming out of find). Using GNU find with -quit would also work, obviously.

Huh! Interesting! Wouldn't have thought that'd be the case.

[[ -n ~Mail/(^(cur|tmp)/)#new/*(#q.NY1) ]] && print 'something!' should work like find -prune ... -quit. Some of the operators require  setopt extendedglob. cc @MarcusMüller

Nitpicking, grep -q . returns true if the input is text and contains at least one line that contains at least one character. For any input ending in a newline (and assuming lines no longer than LINE_MAX bytes), that would rather be LC_ALL=C grep -q '^'. Unlikely to make a difference here in practice as if there's a matching file, its path will contain at least one line containing /Mail/.

Creating a custom hook function is not the only possible approach. An alterative approach is use the shell's built-in functionality for mail notifications. Looking at the man page for zsh, mail notifications are controlled by the following environment vaiables (similar to other shells, e.g. bash, ksh):

MAIL
If this parameter is set and MAILPATH is not set, the shell looks for
mail in the specified file.
MAILCHECK
The interval in seconds between checks for new mail.
MAILPATH
An array (colon-separated list) of filenames to check for new mail. Each filename can be followed by a '?' and a message that will
be printed. The message will undergo parameter expansion, command
substitution and arithmetic expansion with the variable $_ defined as
the name of the file that has changed. The default message is 'You
have new mail'. If an element is a directory instead of a file the
shell will recursively check every file in every subdirectory of the
element.

However, since both MAIL and MAILPATH are geared towards mbox files, this alternative approach requires executing a script to maintain an up-to-date summary of whether there are unseen messages in ~/Mail, e.g. in the file ~/.maildir_unseen, in a way which mimicks an mbox file. The notifications can then be enabled by setting the relevant environment variables, e.g.
export MAILCHECK=60
export MAILPATH="$HOME/.maildir_unseen?you have mail in ~/Mail"

For maintaining ~/.maildir_unseen, options are:

Poll the number of files inside ~/Mail/new, e.g. via a cronjob
Background process which uses a notification mechanism on ~/Mail/new to determine when to update ~/.maildir_unseen. This can be accomplished using inotify-tools, or fwa. For example using fwa:

#!/bin/sh

monitor_source=~/Mail/new
monitor_target=~/.maildir_unseen

update_monitor_target() {
    count=$(find "$monitor_source" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
    if [ "$count" != "0" ]
    then
        echo "$count" > "$monitor_target"
    else
        print -n "" > "$monitor_target"
    fi
}

update_monitor_target

/usr/local/bin/fwa "$monitor_source" | while read -r; do
    update_monitor_target
done


It seems this could be generalised into something that may work for multiple maildir paths too, but not for a setup where new maildirs may be created by incoming mail filters, and where old maildirs may be deleted due to pruning of old messages...  I would probably have used count=$( set -- $monitor_source/*(N); echo $# ) in place for that call to find though (in zsh, not sh).
